# postgres upgrade from 9.5 to 11 changed join to Nested loop making it very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

Recently I upgraded my postgresql from 9.5 to 11.6 after that I have noticed few of my queries taking 50x longer time, after analyzing the query I noticed that the join type was changed in the version 11 from 
Hash Join to Nested Loop Join.
While every thing is same like data set, indexes 
here is the query

```
count(*)
FROM
devices
LEFT OUTER JOIN tests ON tests.device_id = devices.id
AND tests.deleted_at IS NULL
AND(tests.status = 0
OR tests.status = 1
OR tests.status = 2
OR tests.status = 3
OR tests.status = 8)
WHERE
devices.deleted_at IS NULL
AND(tests.id IS NULL)
AND(devices.next_test_date >= '2020-04-12 05:18:00');
AND(devices.next_test_date <= '2020-05-12 05:19:00');
```

**here is the result for EXPLAIN ANALYSE in version 9.5**

```
  ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=57394.39..116654.22 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=450.637..457.209 rows=23900 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (tests.device_id = devices.id)
        Filter: (tests.id IS NULL)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3354
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tests  (cost=5252.89..64186.75 rows=80198 width=16) (actual time=29.369..105.722 rows=42449 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ((status = 0) OR (status = 1) OR (status = 2) OR (status = 3) OR (status = 8))
              Filter: (deleted_at IS NULL)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 62336
              Heap Blocks: exact=37155
              ->  BitmapOr  (cost=5252.89..5252.89 rows=94732 width=0) (actual time=22.435..22.435 rows=0 loops=1)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_tests_on_status  (cost=0.00..2864.08 rows=52754 width=0) (actual time=12.024..12.024 rows=57001 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (status = 0)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_tests_on_status  (cost=0.00..1745.55 rows=32149 width=0) (actual time=6.083..6.083 rows=32221 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (status = 1)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_tests_on_status  (cost=0.00..181.00 rows=3277 width=0) (actual time=0.993..0.993 rows=7065 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (status = 2)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_tests_on_status  (cost=0.00..181.00 rows=3277 width=0) (actual time=2.353..2.353 rows=8767 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (status = 3)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_tests_on_status  (cost=0.00..181.00 rows=3277 width=0) (actual time=0.975..0.975 rows=5242 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (status = 8)
        ->  Hash  (cost=51829.28..51829.28 rows=24978 width=8) (actual time=328.692..328.692 rows=27216 loops=1)
              Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1320kB
              ->  Seq Scan on devices  (cost=0.00..51829.28 rows=24978 width=8) (actual time=0.041..317.112 rows=27216 loops=1)
"                    Filter: ((deleted_at IS NULL) AND (next_test_date >= '2020-04-12 05:18:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (next_test_date <= '2020-05-12 05:19:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 766049
Planning time: 0.362 ms
Execution time: 462.653 ms
```

**EXPLAIN ANALYSE in version 11.6**

```
Aggregate  (cost=13634.81..13634.82 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=466211.022..466211.022 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1858.14..13634.81 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=175.748..466182.183 rows=24085 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (tests.device_id = devices.id)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1139392316
        Filter: (tests.id IS NULL)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3180
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on devices  (cost=102.17..11789.55 rows=20 width=8) (actual time=37.555..428.278 rows=27227 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (deleted_at IS NULL)
"              Filter: ((next_test_date >= '2020-04-12 05:18:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (next_test_date <= '2020-05-12 05:19:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
              Rows Removed by Filter: 678655
              Heap Blocks: exact=39437
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_16425_index_devices_on_deleted_at  (cost=0.00..102.17 rows=3966 width=0) (actual time=31.221..31.221 rows=705882 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (deleted_at IS NULL)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=1755.97..1839.31 rows=20 width=16) (actual time=0.003..8.151 rows=41848 loops=27227)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tests  (cost=1755.97..1839.21 rows=20 width=16) (actual time=79.346..108.975 rows=41848 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: ((deleted_at IS NULL) AND ((status = 0) OR (status = 1) OR (status = 2) OR (status = 3) OR (status = 8)))
                    Heap Blocks: exact=18099
                    ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=1755.97..1755.97 rows=21 width=0) (actual time=76.318..76.319 rows=0 loops=1)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_16490_index_tests_on_deleted_at  (cost=0.00..402.62 rows=826 width=0) (actual time=58.256..58.256 rows=978886 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (deleted_at IS NULL)
                          ->  BitmapOr  (cost=1353.10..1353.10 rows=4131 width=0) (actual time=14.690..14.690 rows=0 loops=1)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_tests_on_status  (cost=0.00..270.62 rows=826 width=0) (actual time=8.690..8.690 rows=67092 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (status = 0)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_tests_on_status  (cost=0.00..270.62 rows=826 width=0) (actual time=3.145..3.145 rows=37208 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (status = 1)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_tests_on_status  (cost=0.00..270.62 rows=826 width=0) (actual time=0.513..0.514 rows=7525 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (status = 2)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_tests_on_status  (cost=0.00..270.62 rows=826 width=0) (actual time=1.639..1.639 rows=15994 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (status = 3)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_tests_on_status  (cost=0.00..270.62 rows=826 width=0) (actual time=0.698..0.699 rows=9117 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (status = 8)
Planning Time: 0.296 ms
Execution Time: 466211.374 ms
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Add the statistics up-to-date  ? What is the output of `select relname, last_analyze, last_autoanalyze from pg_stat_all_tables where relname in ('tests', 'devices');`

Comment: Did you run `vacuum analyze` on all involved tables after the upgrade? If you used `pg_upgrade` it created a batch file `anlayze_new_cluster` for that

Comment: @pifor the result of select pg_stat_all_tables is null :\
please post you reply as answer as you pointed out the problem.

Comment: Try to run at least `analyze` on both tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run at least `analyze` on both tables.